# How to Print character using its unicode value in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x, hindi

I have a list which contains english alphabets, Hindi alphabets, Greek Symbols and digits as well. I want to remove all alphabets except that of Hindi. Hindi alphabets range in unicode is u'0900'-u'097F'. For details about Hindi alphabets visit http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0900-097F.

Input:

```
l=['ग','1ए','==क','@','ऊं','abc123','η','θ','abcशि']

for i in l:
    print i
```

Desired Output:

```
ग
ए
क
ऊं
शि
```

Comment: could you please share the code you wrote so far?

Comment: Is this python2 or python3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a character value you can use the `ord(char)` buildin function.

In your case, something like this should works:

```
strings = [u'ग',u'1ए',u'==क',u'@',u'ऊं',u'abc123',u'η',u'θ',u'abcशि']
for string in strings:
    for char in string:
        if ord(u'\u0900') <= ord(char) <= ord(u'\u097F'):
            print(char)
```

The `ord(char)` function is available for both *Python 2* and *Python 3*

https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html

Comment: @ishpreet I've tested with python 2.7, what do you mean with _'It's not working'_, the output is wrong? did you get some error?

Comment: According to 'Google' odr()->Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer. While i want unicode character given that i have a unicode value. And also Your code is not printing the unicode characters like 'ग' even though it is present in the unicode range

Comment: My bad, I've forgot to update the answer, you must pass explicit unicode string, like `u'ग'`, or it doesn't works

Comment: Not all of them, but that's because of some encoding issues, even my editor encode some of them badly, (e.g. the last one)